# Can I able to align the error message as center which is from aws-amplify-react-native

Tags: react-native, stylesheet, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I need to align the error message to center of the warning icon. It is from aws-amplify-react-native.

Any way to customize this? i am using the screens as it is same from the aws-react-native.

```
    import {
      Authenticator,
      AmplifyTheme,
      Greetings,
      SignIn,
      ConfirmSignIn,
      RequireNewPassword,
      SignUp,
      ConfirmSignUp,
      VerifyContact,
      ForgotPassword,
      AuthPiece,
    } from "aws-amplify-react-native";


render(){
      return(
           <Authenticator errorMessage={map}
                  hideDefault
                  amplifyConfig={awsmobile}
                  signUpConfig={signUpConfig}>
                    <Loading/>
                    <SignIn/>
                    <ConfirmSignIn/>
                    <VerifyContact/>
                    <SignUp signUpConfig={signUpConfig}/>
                    <ConfirmSignUp/>
                    <ForgotPassword/>
                    <RequireNewPassword />
                </Authenticator>
)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'>
<Icon/>
<Text>{warningmessage}</Text>
</View>
```

this alignItems on row will solve your problem.

Comment: don't have Icon or text to make this styles inside my code. I have added my imports in the above question. I am directly using the package imports in my screens.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <Icon/>
    <Text style={{textAlignVertical:"center"}}>{warningmessage}</Text>
    </View>
```

It will center the text **vertically**. Add `textAlign: 'center'` and it will center the text **horizontally**.

Comment: I don't have Icon or text to make this styles inside my code. I have added my imports in the above question